# libxml2.so.2 No version information available

Tags: environment-variables

I repeatedly get the following error when using GRASS GIS and I think a few other programs:

```
/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available ...
```

As far as I can tell I have libxml2 installed at:

```
/usr/local/lib/libxml2/
```

and

```
/usr/local/lib/libxml2-2.7.8/
```

I imagine this has to do with setting an environmental variable somewhere.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do a `locate libxml2.so.2` and see if you have 2 or more versions.
if so delet the old version and create a symbolic link to the new.

`ln -s` is the command to create a symbolic link. The rest of the command requires your file name and the old file name (but depends on what you find with locate ;) )

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind. It turns out I have it in 3 locations.  /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2                   /usr/local/lib/libxml2/lib/libxml2.so.2          and       /usr/local/lib/libxml2-2.7.8/.libs/libxml2.so.2