# php5 libxml2 no version information available error

Tags: php

I keep getting half hourly email messages from the root cron relating to php startup error messages:

Subject:
`Cron <root@hostname>   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -print0 | xargs -n 200 -r -0 rm`

Message content (snipped)
`php5: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by php5)`

Running php -v from a prompt reveals the same:

`php -v

php: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by php)

php: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by php)

<snip>

PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb  9 2012 06:37:37)

Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies`

I did an "apt-get upgrade php5-cli", hence the recent build date.

phpinfo() shows that it is using 2.7.7 of libxml2

Doing a locate on libxml2.so reveals:

`/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2

/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.7

/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so

/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2

/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.3

/var/src/libxml2-2.7.3/.libs/libxml2.so

/var/src/libxml2-2.7.3/.libs/libxml2.so.2

/var/src/libxml2-2.7.3/.libs/libxml2.so.2.7.3`

Server info:

`DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10

DISTRIB_codeNAME=maverick

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"`

FYI, 64bit install on RS cloud.
Linux cfpbbh1 2.6.35.4-rscloud #8 SMP Mon Sep 20 15:54:33 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

This has me baffled, and google isn't helping too much, nothing ubuntu specific at least, lots of cpanel/directadmin options but these arent installed...

There is one other question on this forum with the same problem, with the solution being to have symlinks pointing from the old to the new version... but it seems there already is:

`/usr/lib# ll | grep libxml

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Feb 14 11:54 libxml2.so -> libxml2.so.2.7.7

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Feb 14 12:25 libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.7.7

-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1364056 Jan 18 22:28 libxml2.so.2.7.7`

Anyone care to help? Assistance much appreciated... If someone could tag this with libxml2 it may help others.

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/q/41835/6969

Comment: Hi... yes... I read the solution there, however as I said in the question it seems there are symlinks in /usr/lib dir already

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I ended up in your situation, when I needed a newer version of libxml than the one packaged with my release. I installed it manually, so I ended up with two installations of libxml. What I did was removing all libxml libraries from /usr/local/lib, leaving only packaged libraries in /usr/lib. PHP warnings then disappeared.

Thus you should be able to resolve simply by

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so*
```

You might want to backup libxml2.so* before deletion. Hope this helps someone.